# Passing a variable to .Value function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to set field values in a table using `.Value`, but using a variable for the field name (`rs3!variable.Value=anothervariable`), but it keeps giving me a runtime error (`3265 - Item not found in collection`).  I have tried placing `{}` and `()` around the variable, and it did not help.  Anyone know how I use a variable for the field name?
Pertinent Code:

```
Private Sub GetCMLData_Click()
    Dim IPinfo1 As String
    Dim rs3 As Recordset
    Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("CMLData", dbOpenDynaset)
    Dim AIP2 as string
    AIP2="SomeValue"
    rs3.AddNew
    rs3!IPinfo1.Value = AIP2(i)
    rs3.Update
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have in the table `CMLData` a field with name  `IPinfo1`? If not, it will give you this error. Also what do you mean by using `AIP2(i)`? `AIP2` is string variable, not array, `i` not declared. The string variable IPinfo1 not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using:

```
rs3!variableName.Value = ...
```

you would use:

```
rs3.Fields(variableName) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just - as the *Value* property of a field is the value it holds:

```
rs(IPinfo1).Value = AIP2
```